# Cursor or While loop for set of data

Tags: t-sql

I want a cursor or while loop which will take first set of seq (where seq = 1) and then do the operation, followed by second set seq (where seq = 2) then third set and so on...

Sample code

[image]

Comment: do you mean nested selects?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: ... and can you expand on what you mean by "an then" and "do the operation". By "and then" are you implying that what is done to 2 will depend on what you do to 1? And "do the operation" is a wee bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

First, you will want to define what those operations are. Then you could do either a CASE WHEN THEN clause or a UNION ALL merge.

```
SELECT * 
/* do operation #1 */
FROM table 
WHERE Seq = 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
/* do operation #2 */
FROM table 
WHERE Seq = 2
```

Or you can GROUP BY for aggregate functions such as SUM:

```
SELECT Seq, SUM(cost) AS Total
FROM table 
GROUP BY Seq
```

Which should output:

```
Seq  Total

1   4400
2   56400
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but this will help only when seq is 1,2 or 3 but what if its 10000 then its Impossible to write 10000 union all statement.

Comment: What about CASE WHEN THEN or GROUP BY? Are the operations aggregate (or different). If different, how many different operations are there? If different operations are needed on a case-by-case a server-side script such as PHP would be helpful.